# Excel 2010 formula to track records and replace them when surpassed or bettered

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I've found using game data is an excellent way to learn the ins and outs of Excel. I made a workbook complete with personally made achievements (all of which work), but I can't find a formula that will save pre-existing data from one cell into another cell before writing new data in.

I need this in order to automatically keep track of missions/kills, not only current but also highest.

For example, if three missions in a character has 5 kills, his M/K would be 3/5, a difference of +2, and until this record is broken I want a cell remembering it. Once it is broken, I want it automatically replaced.

I already have the formula to display M/K in +- format (`=IMSUB(-B2,-C2)` as an example), but this condenses two cells into one and is unusable for my current problem. Any input would be appreciated.

Basically, I want to create an automatic system of cells that track records (in the achievement sense of the word) and replace them as they are broken. Manually typing it every time would work, but does nothing to grow my understanding, which is the reason I do any of this in the first place.

Portland did offer a viable solution, but it still lacks one ability, that of being able to differentiate between the difference values. Using my 3/5 example in the original question, I want the formula (or chain of them) to differentiate and only replace the second cell when a greater record is obtained, say 7/10. The first is +2, while the second is a +3 and thus is a better record. The intermediate 4/5, 5/6, and 6/8 would be irrelevant to this cause, because none are greater than +2.

Comment: You can set up a vba macro to run before cell change.  It would watch a specific cell and when a change takes place it will copy the text prior (before) change into another cell.

Comment: Besides Runner's suggestion, why not write in a cell that has nothing in it and no links. It is hard to understand your problem... maybe you're approaching the problem in a wrong way.

Comment: At any rate, how are you storing missions and kills? in separate columns? If so, I think you could simply use a MAX function, with some creative processes. Please give an example of what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution to your problem. I am assuming you are writing the mission and kills information manually (at least).

Assume you have this situation:

[image: Initial situation]

A and B columns are manually fed. M/K is got through the following formula (I described for C2)

```
=SUM($B$2:B2)-A2
```

Note the `$B$2`. This means that when you drag down the formula, the beginning will always be fixed, counting all individual kills you made in each mission.

The Rank (i.e. what you wanted) can be got through the following function:

```
=MAX(C:C)
```

As you can see, the rank is 5 although the latest M/K is 4. This is due to the fact the previous formula only counts kills up to the current mission. Adding more values will refresh the rank only when the M/K is bigger than 5, due to the max function being used. You can hide the C column, as to not make anyone aware of it's existence.

The following is the end result:

[image: End result]